# Does android have a maximum number of handlers?

Tags: android, android-handler

I have an app that has quite a large number of handlers in it and some of them seem to be stopping randomly, and as luck would have it, its the more important ones. Is there a maximum number of handlers than can be running at one time or is it more than likely a problem with the code that some of them are not being reset?

Please do not ask for code, the project is huge, >20,000 lines of code so posting every instance of a handler is not feasible, I just want to know if there is a limit to the number of handlers you can have running at any one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no a limit but If there is too much work to do in one time Android kills threads/handlers.

Instead create too much handlers try do it like this:
[Multiple threads](http://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/run-code.html)

Comment: the problem is a lot of them need to be running at the same time. Would threads that are waiting to access a critical section be included in the list of thread trying to do too much ?

Comment: I think yes, If there is too much. Maybe you can try do less handlers by combining few handlers into one.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at trying to do that. there are quite a number of things done wrong in terms of concurrency in the early stages of this project before I started working on it that are now becoming bigger issues